# Grape API group parameter not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api

I want to create a post method in grape where i want to collect all the params once

currently I am using it like

```
params do
  requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "post id"
  requires :title, type: String, desc: "Title"
end
post do
  post = Post.new(:id => params[:id],:title => params[:tile])
end
```

after  googling I found something like

```
params do
  group :post do
    requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "post id"
    requires :title, type: String, desc: "Title"
  end
end

post do
  #post = Post.new(params[:post])
  #post.save
end 
but it is also asking for post hash
```

I also want to file upload (i.e params to add file)

Answer (score 3):

Your code will work if you declare the `:post` group as a `Hash` type ([the default type is `Array`](https://github.com/intridea/grape#parameter-validation-and-coercion)):

```
params do
  group :post, type: Hash do
    requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "post id"
    requires :title, type: String, desc: "Title"
  end
end
```

However, what this does is a bit different from what you're expecting: It defines a `post` parameter with `id` and `title` as *subscripts*. So the data your endpoint is expecting now looks like this:

```
post[id]=100&post[title]=New+article
```

What you're trying to do here is unnecessary anyway, though. Since `params` is a hash with the names of the endpoint parameters as keys, and the attributes your `Post` object is expecting are named identically to your endpoint parameters, you can simply do this:

```
params do
  requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "post id"
  requires :title, type: String, desc: "Title"
end
post do
  post = Post.new(params)
end
```

Of course **you should always sanitize any data you receive from the user** before acting on it, so this kind of shortcut is appropriate only for personal or prototype-quality apps.